# Method POST not working when send request to REST Service

Tags: java, javascript, rest

My problem look like this: When i send POST request to REST Service I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, but request GET it's working.

This is my Rest Service:

```
@Path("/createUser")
@RequestScoped
public class ClientRestService {

@Inject
private ClientManager clientManager;

@POST
@Path("{name}/{surname}/{adress}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createUser(@PathParam("name")String name,  @PathParam("surname")String surname, @PathParam("adress")String adress) {
    Client client = new Client(name,surname,adress);


    Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok("POST It's working.!!!");
    builder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    builder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    return builder.build();
}

@GET
public Response getMetod() {
    Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok("GET It's working.");
    builder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return builder.build();
}
}
```

This is client:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Bank_Project_Test/MyApp/createUser',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'name=SomeName'+
        '&surname=SomeSurname'+
        '&adress=SomeAdress', 
    success: function(success) {
        alert(success); 
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690811/does-responsebuilder-work-with-get-request-but-not-post

Answer (score 0):

Might fail because of cors preflight requests?

If you see `OPTIONS`-method requests in the browser when things fail, then you need to handle those in your server implementation as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests